# How to reference input in params section of snakemake rule?

Tags: python, snakemake

I need to process my input file values, turning them into a comma-separated string (instead of white space) in order to pass them to a CLI program. To do this, I want to run the input files through a Python function. How can I reference the input files of a rule in the params section of the same rule?

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
rule a:
    input:
        foo="a.txt",
        bar=expand({build}.txt,build=config["build"]),
    output:
        baz=result.txt,
    params:
        joined_bar=lambda w: ",".join(input.bar),  # this doesn't work
    shell:
        """
        qux --comma-separated-files {params.joined_bar} \
            --foo {input.foo} \
            >{output.baz}
        """
```

It fails with:

```
InputFunctionException:
   AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'bar'
```

Potentially related but (over-)complicated questions: 
[How to define parameters for a snakemake rule with expand input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72077735/how-to-define-parameters-for-a-snakemake-rule-with-expand-input) 
[Is Snakemake params function evaluated before input file existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636844/is-snakemake-params-function-evaluated-before-input-file-existence)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I need to explicitly add `input` to the `lambda w:` part:

```
rule a:
    input:
        foo="a.txt",
        bar=expand({build}.txt,build=config["build"]),
    output:
        baz=result.txt,
    params:
        joined_bar=lambda w, input: ",".join(input.bar),  # ', input' was added
    shell:
        """
        qux --comma-separated-files {params.joined_bar} \
            --foo {input.foo} \
            >{output.baz}
        """
```

Interestingly, I found that one needs to use `input` in the `lambda w, input`. In my testing, `lambda w, i` did not work.

And alternative is to refer to the rule input in the standard way: `rules.a.input.bar`:

```
rule a:
    input:
        foo="a.txt",
        bar=expand({build}.txt,build=config["build"]),
    output:
        baz=result.txt,
    params:
        joined_bar=lambda w: ",".join(rules.a.input.bar),  # 'rules.a.' was added
    shell:
        """
        qux --comma-separated-files {params.joined_bar} \
            --foo {input.foo} \
            >{output.baz}
        """
```

Also see http://biolearnr.blogspot.com/2017/11/snakemake-using-inputoutput-values-in.html for a discussion.